# how to get last row from table 2 using left join mysql

Tags: mysql

I have tow tables `tbl_product_checkout` and `tbl_product_checkout_status` in which I want to get the last row from `tbl_product_checkout_status`

```
//tbl_product_checkout

product_checkout_id    user_id    product_checkout_order_no
-----------------------------------------------------------
        1                 1              ORD123456


//tbl_product_checkout_status

checkout_status_id    product_checkout_id    checkout_status_check
------------------------------------------------------------------
        1                      1                  Dispatched
        2                      1                  Delivered
```

I have tried using the following query

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl_product_checkout pc 
  LEFT 
  JOIN tbl_product_checkout_status cs 
    ON cs.product_checkout_id = pc.product_checkout_id  
 WHERE pc.user_id = 1 
 GROUP 
    BY pc.product_checkout_id 
 ORDER 
    BY cs.checkout_status_id DESC
```

but the output for above query is,

```
user_id    product_checkout_order_no    checkout_status_check
-------------------------------------------------------------
   1              ORD123456                  Dispatched
```

but I want the result as,

```
user_id    product_checkout_order_no    checkout_status_check
-------------------------------------------------------------
   1              ORD123456                  Delivered
```

Comment: Is there any auto increment field in the tables

Comment: @MHRasel yes. `product_checkout_id` and `checkout_status_id`

Comment: Then use the max() to get the last row

Comment: If ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled, a MySQL extension to the standard SQL use of GROUP BY permits the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list to refer to nonaggregated columns even if the columns are not functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns. This causes MySQL to accept the preceding query. In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: @MHRasel how to use `max()`

Comment: use `tbl_product_checkout_status` as base table and avoid group by, then you will get the latest status

Comment: @VijayArun show some example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a where = max sub query eg

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_product_checkout,tbl_product_checkout_status;

CREATE TABLE tbl_product_checkout(product_checkout_id INT,   user_id INT,   product_checkout_order_no VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO tbl_product_checkout VALUES
(        1       ,          1  ,            'ORD123456');


CREATE TABLE tbl_product_checkout_status(checkout_status_id INT,   product_checkout_id INT,    checkout_status_check VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO tbl_product_checkout_status VALUES
(        1      ,                1 ,                 'Dispatched'),
(        2      ,                1 ,                 'Delivered');

SELECT * FROM
tbl_product_checkout T1
LEFT JOIN tbl_product_checkout_status T2 ON T1.PRODUCT_CHECKOUT_ID = T2.PRODUCT_CHECKOUT_ID
WHERE T2.CHECKOUT_STATUS_ID = (
SELECT MAX(T3.CHECKOUT_STATUS_ID) 
FROM tbl_product_checkout_status T3 
WHERE T3.PRODUCT_CHECKOUT_ID = T2.PRODUCT_CHECKOUT_ID
)
;
```

Result

```
+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| product_checkout_id | user_id | product_checkout_order_no | checkout_status_id | product_checkout_id | checkout_status_check |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|                   1 |       1 | ORD123456                 |                  2 |                   1 | Delivered             |
+---------------------+---------+---------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your group by mess up your desired outcome. I worked on your given database schema and cretaed a fiddle and managed to get your desired outcome. So your sql should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_product_checkout as pc 
LEFT JOIN tbl_product_checkout_status as cs ON 
cs.product_checkout_id = pc.product_checkout_id 
WHERE pc.user_id = 1 ORDER BY cs.checkout_status_id DESC limit 1
```

By using limit 1, you will get last row as we ordered by DESC.

Keep in mind that i removed date part since there was no date on your example code.

[Check Out Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9fbc7a/18)

Comment: don't use `LIMIT`